# Vertical Centering of CSS Sprite and Text

Tags: html, css, sprite

I'm working on developing a simple nav element within a website, and am trying to use a sprite page to add images to the "Last" and "Next" text buttons. I can get them all to display properly, but the text will not center vertically on those elements. Anyone have any suggestions?

```
<div class="post_nav">
    <div class="last">Last</div>
    <div class="home">&nbsp;</div>
    <div class="next">Next</div>
</div>


.post_nav { position: relative; width: 30%; margin: 10px auto; text-align: center; font-family: 'Bitter', Georgia, serif; font-weight: 700; color: #c9c9c9; }
.post_nav div { display: inline-block; text-transform: uppercase; padding: 0 20px; }
.post_nav .last:before { content: ""; width: 30px; height: 30px; line-height: 20px ; background: url('http://i.imgur.com/BlY1jqF.png') no-repeat -60px 0; float: left; margin: auto 5px; overflow: hidden; }
.post_nav .home:before { content: ""; width: 30px; height: 30px; line-height: 30px ; background: url('http://i.imgur.com/BlY1jqF.png') no-repeat -120px 0; float: left; margin: auto 5px; padding: 0; overflow: hidden; }
.post_nav .next:after { content: ""; width: 30px; height: 30px; line-height: 30px ; background: url('http://i.imgur.com/BlY1jqF.png') no-repeat -90px 0; float: right; margin: auto 5px; overflow: hidden; }
```

[Here's the Fiddle for this issue.](https://jsfiddle.net/jj7494vL/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't float the `pseudo-elements`, make them `inline-block` and then vertically align them.

Also, the CSS was rather repetetive, you can simplify a lot of that.

```css
.post_nav {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 10px auto;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: 'Bitter', Georgia, serif;
  font-weight: 700;
  color: #c9c9c9;
}
.post_nav div {
  display: inline-block;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  padding: 0 20px;
}
.post_nav div::before,
.post_nav div::after {
  content: "";
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  margin: 0 5px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.post_nav .last::before {
  background: url('http://i.imgur.com/BlY1jqF.png') no-repeat -60px 0;
}
.post_nav .home::before {
  background: url('http://i.imgur.com/BlY1jqF.png') no-repeat -120px 0;
}
.post_nav .next::after {
  background: url('http://i.imgur.com/BlY1jqF.png') no-repeat -90px 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="post_nav">
  <div class="last">Last</div>
  <div class="home">&nbsp;</div>
  <div class="next">Next</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jj7494vL/1/), I think it's what you are looking for

Add CSS

```
.post_nav div {line-height: 30px;}
```

Comment: Why is it always the dumbest things that I leave out? :(  Thank you so much.